# Any way To disable The next and Last Button Of PagingTollbar?

Tags: extjs

I'am Using pagination in my grid.The grid store have no data but in  pagination toolbar the

next and last button is enable .What is the reason for that? I can't Understand it.

Any One Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it. see answers of [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226311/extjs-grid-paging-next-button-is-disabled) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647185/extjs-4-how-to-disable-next-last-icons-in-the-paging-toolbar-when-no-rec).

Also, you can enable/disable it by using methods of DOM elements, on afterRender function.